# how to send multiple pairs (key , value) to the Xadd command using java?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

// I have tried to send the multiple values to the streams using XAdd command.

public class LettuceDemo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("redis://password@localhost:6739/0");
    StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection =redisClient.connect();

    RedisStreamCommands<String, String> streamCommands = connection.sync();

     List<String> supplierNames1 = new ArrayList<String>();
     supplierNames1.add("PaymentOption");
     supplierNames1.add("StartDate");
     supplierNames1.add("EndDate");
     supplierNames1.add("RateOfInterest");
     supplierNames1.add("RequiredLoanAmmount");

     List<String> supplierNames2 = new ArrayList<String>();
     supplierNames2.add(String.valueOf(123));
     supplierNames2.add(String.valueOf(765));
     supplierNames2.add(String.valueOf(347746));
     supplierNames2.add(String.valueOf(8347674));
     supplierNames2.add(String.valueOf(34875645));

    Map<List<String>, List<String>> body1 =  Collections.singletonMap(supplierNames1, supplierNames2);
        String messageId = streamCommands.xadd("demo", body1);

    System.out.println("my-stream code reference " + messageId);
    connection.close();
    redisClient.shutdown();


}
```

}

// I facing the issue while executing the program.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Message >body.length must be a multiple of 2 and contain a sequence of field1, >value1, field2, value2, fieldN, valueN
>     at io.lettuce.core.internal.LettuceAssert.isTrue(LettuceAssert.java:131)
>     at io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandBuilder.xadd(RedisCommandBuilder.java:2110)
>     at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.xadd(AbstractRedisAsyncCommands.java:1499)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at io.lettuce.core.FutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(FutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:57)
>       at io.lettuce.core.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.xadd(Unknown Source)
>       at com.excent.experiences.tinnumber.LettuceDemo.main(LettuceDemo.java:48)

[image]

Comment: Did you really tried to create a   Map<List<String>, List<String>>? My guess is that you tried to create a Map<String, String>, right?